# Google Calendar is returning empty list of calendars in java

Tags: java, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to retrieve list and detail of calender from my google calendar in java. I am using service account so using p12 file for OAuth. Can some one please suggest if have faced same issue ?

Thanks in advance!!!!

Code Used to retrieve list :
**System.out.println("CalendarSample.showCalendars()1111 ---> "+client.calendarList().list());**

**CalendarList feed = client.calendarList().list().execute();**

exception getting on it :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:191)
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:127)
    at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.createJsonParser(JacksonFactory.java:96)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:85)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:88)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:269)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at calendarevents.CalendarSample.showCalendars(CalendarSample.java:190)
    at calendarevents.CalendarSample.main(CalendarSample.java:147)
```

Comment: Try creating a calendar by the service account and see if the list works then.

Answer (score 0):

I had tproblem, when I changed the mail account in the google console developer, and created a new project, everything was ok and working perfectly before this, but the error you mention start appearing all the time, so I decided to comeback to my previous gmail account configuration that it was working perfectly before, but this error appears too with this configuration and when I attempt to show all the calendars associated with my account it fails with the NPE.

So, you can try with the google api samples, in this case google calendar sample, and if you are using stores to save credentials -client_secrets.json- this creates a tiny file in your user folder - in my case it is C:\Users\myUser.store\calendar_sample, the file is StoredCredential, so you can delete this file and try again, when you run the example, it will ask you to set permission again for your google account, and everything would worked again.